# Power Automate - Update a list item based on a SharePoint site based on the status of a list item on a different SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Goal: I want to update a list item on a SharePoint site based on the status of a list item on a different SharePoint site.

Details:
When an item is created on a list on the ACN Sharepoint Site, it is automatically created on a list on the TG SharePoint site.  I have that working.

Issue:  I've watched YouTube videos and searched Google but cannot find a solution that works.
When the list item is updated on the TG SharePoint site, I want the list item on the ACN SharePoint site to reflect the same update and send an email to a specific individual.

Appreciate any help I can get!

Thank you!

Comment: This is too hard to answer, you're essentially wanting someone to build the entire flow.  You need to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.